# Problem with Python Scientific Notation Suppress

Tags: python, python-3.x, scientific-notation

To make things short, I have scientific notation 4.534524725984957e+16 and I am trying to get the suppression..

The correct number here is 45345247259849570...but python keeps returning wrong numbers like 45345247259849568...any ideas?

Comment: What is a suppression?

Comment: How are you trying to get it? Are you aware of how finite-precision IEEE-754 doubles are stored?

Comment: Are you looking for floating point formatting? Use `f"{mynumber:.6e}"` or similar. See https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language (scroll down until you find "float and Decimal values").

Comment: "wrong numbers" is not true. Search around for "floating point numbers precision". Your computer's CPU has a precision limit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recall that a Python `float` is a C [`double`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format) under the hood.  It's stored in *binary* scientific notation.

In binary, the 56-bit integer 45345247259849570 is represented as 101000010001100101000011000110110010110011110011**01100010**.  Or in scientific notation, 1.01000010001100101000011000110110010110011110011**01100010** × 2<sup>55</sup>.  (I've bolded the least-significant digits bolded for comparison.)

The thing is, only 53 significant digits can be stored.  So your number gets rounded down to 1.01000010001100101000011000110110010110011110011**01100** × 2<sup>55</sup>, which works out to 453452472598495**68** in decimal.

If you're not willing to accept this rounding error, the solution is to use the proper data type to store your numbers.

The built-in `int` (or `long` if you're still using Python 2.x) can exactly store any integer (whole number) that can fit in a process's memory.  Of course, it doesn't work if you have digits to the right of the decimal point.

[`decimal.Decimal`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html) is a floating-point type that stores 28 decimal digits by default.  It's great for financial calculations, in which “$0.01” means exactly 1/100 of a dollar, and not 0.01000000000000000020816681711721685132943093776702880859375.

```py
>>> from decimal import Decimal
>>> Decimal('4.534524725984957e+16')
Decimal('4.534524725984957E+16')
```

However, non-decimal fractions like 1/3 are still only approximated.

```py
>>> Decimal(1) / Decimal(3)
Decimal('0.3333333333333333333333333333')
>>> _ * 3
Decimal('0.9999999999999999999999999999')
```

[`fractions.Fraction`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fractions.html) will exactly store any rational number as a numerator/denominator pair.

```py
>>> from fractions import Fraction
>>> Fraction('4.534524725984957e+16')
Fraction(45345247259849570, 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Floating-point literals give the appearance of more precision than the `float` type actually provides. Python does its best to map such a literal to value that's close to what you want.

```
>>> float(45345247259849570)
4.534524725984957e+16
>>> float(45345247259849568)
4.534524725984957e+16
>>> float(45345247259849570) == float(45345247259849568)
True
>>> float(45345247259849570) == 4.534524725984957e+16
True
```